# Date to UTC in momentjs

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I am trying to convert my date to UTC using momentjs:

```
var some_date = 06/06/2016
var new_date = moment(new Date(some_date)).utc().format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm");
console.log(new_date)
```

> 2016-06-06 04:00

My date is still returned in EDT... Can someone help me get it to show in UTC instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the utc() method of moment when creating:

```
var some_date = '06/06/2016';
console.log(moment.utc(new Date(some_date)).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm'))
console.log(moment(new Date(some_date)).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm'));
```

EDIT: best practice based on @Maggie's comment

```
 console.log(moment.utc(some_date, 'MM/DD/YYYY').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm'));
 console.log(moment(some_date, 'MM/DD/YYYY').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm'));
```

Outputs:

```
2016-06-06 04:00
2016-06-06 00:00
```

Comment: This is generally correct, but as a matter of best practice, it is not good to use the Date constructor. Instead, specify the format and have moment parse the date for more consistent results. moment.utc(some_date, 'MM/DD/YYYY').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm') is what we would consider best practice on the moment team.

Comment: I updated the answer to include that for folks in the future who might miss your comment. Thanks.